# rotation on the axis of a moving body

Tags: java, processing

I'm just learning how to use push and pop matrices. I want the car(object) to rotate on its axis and not(revolve) with the 0,0 of the translated coordinate. {Beginner programming hobbyist}

Tried re-translating the axes when I use rotate().

```
PImage c = new PImage();

Car forza = new Car();
Trees tr = new Trees();

float wrap = 100;

void setup(){
  size(800,800);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  forza.update();
  forza.display();
  tr.road();
}

class Car {

  float posX;
  float posY;
  float speed;
  float accel;
  float angle;

  Car(){
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    speed = .9;
    angle = sin(0);
    accel = 0;
  }


  void update(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(posX,posY);
    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == 'd') {
        angle += 1;
      }else if (key == 'a'){
        angle -= 1;
        rotate(radians(angle));
      } else if (key == 'w'){
        posX += speed;
      } else if (key == 's'){
        posX -= speed;
      }
    }  
    popMatrix();
  }

  void display(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2,height/2);
    rotate(radians(angle));
    c = loadImage("car.jpg");
    fill(255);
    stroke(255);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(c,posX,posY,wrap,wrap);
    line(0,0,posX,posY);
    print(posX);
    println(posY);
    popMatrix();
  }

}

class Trees {
  float x;
  float y;

  Trees(){
    //x = random(0,);
  }

  void trash(){

  }
  void road(){
    fill(250,50);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2,height/2, width/2, height);
  }

  void show(){

  }
}
```

I just wanna know the algorithm for it, and if any other way of doing the algorithm in terms of efficiency and aesthetics. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object should rotate around its origin, then the rotation has to be done before the translation. Since operations like [`rotate()`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) and [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) set a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix, this means that `rotate()` has to be done last before drawing the object. Even drawing an object at the a certain position (e.g. `posX`, `posY`) behaves like a translation.

You have to draw the car at position (0, 0). Then you've to rotate it. Finally translate it to its final position:

```java
void display(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2,height/2);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(posX,posY);
    rotate(radians(angle));

    fill(255);
    stroke(255);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(c,0,0,wrap,wrap);
    popMatrix();

    line(0,0,posX,posY);
    popMatrix();
}
```

The matrix manipulation operations, change the matrix. The matrix is applied to the coordinates in of the drawing operations. The matrix operations in `update` are useless, because at the begin is a [`pushMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) at the end a [`popMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html), but nothing is draw at all.

It is a wast of performance, to load the image in every frame, do it once in the constructor of `Car`.

See the example:

[image]

```java
Car forza;
Trees tr;
float wrap = 100;

void setup(){
    size(800,800);
    forza = new Car();
    tr = new Trees();
}

void draw(){
    background(0);
    forza.update();
    forza.display();
    tr.road();
}

class Car {

    float posX;
    float posY;
    float speed;
    float accel;
    float angle;
    PImage c;

    Car(){
        posX = 0;
        posY = 0;
        speed = .9;
        angle = sin(0);
        accel = 0;
        c = loadImage("car.jpg");
    }

    void update(){
        if (keyPressed) {
          if (key == 'd') {
            angle += 1;
          }else if (key == 'a'){
            angle -= 1;
          } else if (key == 'w'){
            posX += speed;
          } else if (key == 's'){
            posX -= speed;
          }
        }  
    }

    void display(){
        pushMatrix();
        translate(width/2,height/2);

        pushMatrix();
        translate(posX,posY);
        rotate(radians(angle));

        fill(255);
        stroke(255);
        imageMode(CENTER);
        image(c,0,0,wrap,wrap);
        popMatrix();

        line(0,0,posX,posY);
        popMatrix();
    }
}

class Trees {
    float x;
    float y;

    Trees(){
      //x = random(0,);
    }

    void trash(){

    }
    void road(){
      fill(250,50);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(width/2,height/2, width/2, height);
    }

    void show(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know you can use more than one matrix transformation. It did work as intended, but after translating I still wanted to be able to change the positioning of the object within that translated matrix[move the object in the direction of x or y]/still be able to move the object to the direction it's rotated to. How would that be coded?